# How can I run Wireshark in Windows Safe Mode

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, wireshark, safe-mode

I'm trying to replicate a customer problem so I can troubleshoot. They're sending data down to our product at 5ms, according to the Wireshark logs they sent us. Because my company's computers are bogged down with so much security bloat and other software, they're basically useless at replicating the problem. The fastest I can seem to send data is at 80ms. I figured I could speed that up a bit by running the computer in safe mode (with networking) to prevent excess bloatware from hogging up resources. However, that also meant that the npf driver that Wireshark uses does not start either. Trying to run it manually with the commands as per [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/315439/why-do-i-see-the-npf-driver-isnt-running-you-may-have-trouble-capturing-or-li) results in [this command line output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5QBw.jpg). Is there any way to get around this and run the NFP driver in Safe Mode? I'm not super concerned with security, I'm not dealing with networking or servers, I'm dealing with an embedded system (power supply) that communicates over ethernet.

--- EDIT---

I'm trying to measure the time between successive commands from the source (Windows 7 64-bit machine). I want to achieve 5ms per command sent.

Comment: ms is a measure of latency in network situations, not speed, so I'm not sure what the problem is that you're trying to describe. Also, what version of Windows are you working with? Please use the EDIT button and add this information and clarification to your original question. Consider also using formatting to improve the readability of the question.

Comment: @music2myear done

Comment: Do you have network access in Safe Mode?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned, I'm running `safe mode (with networking)`

Comment: Could you use another PC to run Wireshark on? Use a port mirroring switch so the other PC can see the packets destined for the target machine.